# React Firebase startAfter() query not working as intended

Tags: reactjs, firebase, infinite-scroll

I'm working on infinite pagination in React using Firebase Firestore. I have a single component that's fetching limited data from my firestore and appending it to state. Initially, I fetch only 5 records and I fire the same function to fetch the next 5 records after the last record of the previous fetch.

```
import './App.css';
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import db from './firebase.config';

function App() {
  const [comments,setComments]=useState([])
  async function fetchData(){
    let latestDoc=comments[comments.length-1];
    console.log(latestDoc)
    const res=db.collection('comments')
      .orderBy("id")
      .startAfter(latestDoc || 0)
      .limit(5);
    const data=await res.get();
    console.log(data.docs)
    let temp=[];
    data.docs.forEach(item=>{
      const comment=item.data();
      temp.push(comment)
    })
    setComments([...comments,...temp])
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchData();
  },[])
  const LoadMoreData=()=>{
    fetchData();
  }
  return (
    <>
    <div className="container">
        {
          comments && comments.map(comment=>{
            if(comment)
            return(
              <div className="card" key={comment.id}>
                <h4>{comment.name}</h4>
                <p>{comment.email}</p>
                <p>{comment.postId}</p>
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
    </div>
    <div className="load">
      <button onClick={LoadMoreData}>Load More</button>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I click load more, the last record is correctly stored inside `latestDoc` however the `startAfter()` query is giving me an empty array when it shouldn't for the subsequent fetches. My firestore data is nothing but all the comments returned by this dummy API https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments . What am I doing wrong and why isn't my query working as it's supposed to?

Comment: In the `startAfter()` try using the comment Id instead of the whole object. In your first run you are using index while subsequent run you use whole object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.startAfter(latestDoc?latestDoc.id : 0)
```

The above change worked for me. Thanks to @kunquan for pointing out. Looks like you need to refer to the record's property that you are using inside the `orderBy` clause which in my case was `id`.